# Retrieve contacts from local address

Tags: java, android, sdk

I'm getting all the contacts from the local address book, together with their names + phone numbers but the problem is it's return e-mail addresses that I exchanged mails with and also Skype ID's, things I don't need :)

```
public void fetchContacts() {
        String phoneNumber = null;
        String email = null;

        Uri CONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
        String _ID = ContactsContract.Contacts._ID;
        String DISPLAY_NAME = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME;
        String HAS_PHONE_NUMBER = ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER;
        Uri PhoneCONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
        String Phone_CONTACT_ID = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID;
        String NUMBER = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER;

        Uri EmailCONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI;
        String EmailCONTACT_ID = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID;
        String DATA = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA;
        StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();

        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();

        Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

        // Loop for every contact in the phone
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                String contact_id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(_ID));
                String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DISPLAY_NAME));
                int hasPhoneNumber = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)));
                if (hasPhoneNumber > 0) {
                    output.append("\n Name:" + name);
                    // Query and loop for every phone number of the contact
                    Cursor phoneCursor = contentResolver.query(PhoneCONTENT_URI, null, Phone_CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[]{contact_id}, null);
                    while (phoneCursor.moveToNext()) {
                        phoneNumber = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(NUMBER));
                        output.append("\n Phone number:" + phoneNumber);
                    }
                    phoneCursor.close();
                    // Query and loop for every email of the contact
                }
                output.append("\n");
            }
            outputText.setText(output);
        }


 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not Android-related, but rather a Java issue.

In your largest `while` loop make sure a `continue` keyword in the `hasPhoneNumber` IF, or just move the `output.append("\n")` into the IF.

Cheers. :-)